# WPF Formatting Currency Column from code behind

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am using xceed datagridcontrol, which i think is very similar to DataGrid.
I loaded the grid rows and columns using ObservableCollection of my Business Object class. So far so good, all the properties in the B O automatically translated as the grid columns, the rows all shows up good.

I want to format some of the columns to display in currency format. I've read some questions and answers related to this, and all of them use binding to the column and its stringFormat attribute. Since i'm not declaring the columns in XAML, but instead the grid reads automatically from my B O, i am looking for a way to change the format from code behind. Something like DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Format in winforms.

Thanks

Edit:

Okay... if it is not possible, XAML solution also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another unanswered question. sob sob. Anyway... after some days searching and experimenting, I created a data template and define a CurrencyConverter : IValueConverter class:

```
    <local:CurrencyConverter x:Key="CC"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CurrencyCellTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CC}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And set the style with this:

```
        foreach (int idx in moneyColumns) {
            var col = TheGrid.Columns[idx];
            col.CellHorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            DataTemplate DT = FindResource("CurrencyCellTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            col.CellContentTemplate = DT;
        }
```

Perhaps this self answer could help somebody in the future.